# Add blank space in record edit form LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, slds-grid

I have an LWC Record Page component that has two columns. The two columns have almost the same number of fields with one exception. I need to add a blank space on the second column:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-clearfix">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <h1 style="padding: 2px 4px;">RINs</h1>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProjectNameRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProjectActivityRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProjectCountryRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={EntityRegisteredRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProjectStartDateRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProgramStatusRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProgramIdRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={FeedRINGrade}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={PathwayRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ConversionTechRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={RefiningTechRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={FuelDisplacementRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={CAPEXRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={OtherDetailsRIN}>
        </lightning-input-field>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <h1 style="padding: 2px 4px;">LCFS</h1>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProjectNameLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProjectActivityLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProjectCountryLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={EntityRegisteredLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProjectStartDateLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProgramStatusLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ProgramIdLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <br>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={PathwayLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={ConversionTechLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={RefiningTechLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={FuelDisplacementLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={CAPEXLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={OtherDetailsLCFS}>
        </lightning-input-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using <br*> but is not enough
[image]

How can I make it so the fields on the two columns are aligned?

Answer (score 1):

When using SLDS grids, you need to create rows, not columns. The following conversion should do what you want:

```
<lightning-layout multiple-rows>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <h1 style="padding: 2px 4px">RINs</h1>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <h1 style="padding: 2px 4px">LCFS</h1>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProjectNameRIN}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProjectNameLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProjectActivityRIN}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProjectActivityLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProjectCountryRIN}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProjectCountryLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={EntityRegisteredRIN}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={EntityRegisteredLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProjectStartDateRIN}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProjectStartDateLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProgramStatusRIN}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProgramStatusLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProgramIdRIN}> </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ProgramIdLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={FeedRINGrade}> </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <!-- empty space here -->
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={PathwayRIN}> </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={PathwayLCFS}> </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ConversionTechRIN}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={ConversionTechLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={RefiningTechRIN}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={RefiningTechLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={FuelDisplacementRIN}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={FuelDisplacementLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={CAPEXRIN}> </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={CAPEXLCFS}> </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={OtherDetailsRIN}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
  <lightning-layout-item size="6">
    <lightning-input-field field-name={OtherDetailsLCFS}>
    </lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

Comment: That's a good approach. I can do a similar thing using SLDS Grid if I modify my code, but I was wondering if it's a quicker way, like a div with a class or certain standard style that I don't know about. Maybe a way of using input field with blank/null value (or even a break line)

Comment: @Alex There's no way to do so that's supported in SLDS. You could make a div that's `display: inline-block; height: 3em` or something like that, but you risk horizontal misalignment. You should use rows instead of columns. Though, if you build a list of fields in your controller, you could use an iteration (`for:each`) to reduce the size of your code significantly.